# How do I multiply a pandas column with a part of a multi index dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiplication

I have a data frame with a multi index and one column.

Index fields are `type` and `amount`, the column is called `count`

I would like to add a column that multiplies `amount` and `count`

```
df2 = df.groupby(['type','amount']).count().copy()
# I then dropped all columns but one and renamed it to "count"

df2['total_amount'] = df2['count'].multiply(df2['amount'], axis='index')
```

doesn't work. I get a key error on `amount`.

How do I access a part of the multi index to use it in calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `Series` with same size as original `df` with aggregated values, so possible `multiple`:

```
count = df.groupby(['type','amount'])['type'].transform('count')
df['total_amount'] = df['amount'].multiply(count, axis='index')
print (df)
   A  amount  C  D  E type  total_amount
0  a       4  7  1  5    a             8
1  b       5  8  3  3    a             5
2  c       4  9  5  6    a             8
3  d       5  4  7  9    b            10
4  e       5  2  1  2    b            10
5  f       4  3  0  4    b             4
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'amount':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'type':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  amount  C  D  E type
0  a       4  7  1  5    a
1  b       5  8  3  3    a
2  c       4  9  5  6    a
3  d       5  4  7  9    b
4  e       5  2  1  2    b
5  f       4  3  0  4    b

df2 = df.groupby(['type','amount'])['type'].count().to_frame('count')
df2['total_amount'] = df2['count'].mul(df2.index.get_level_values('amount'))
print (df2)
             count  total_amount
type amount                     
a    4           2             8
     5           1             5
b    4           1             4
     5           2            10
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost seems to work, but I need to use `df2['amount']`...